# How to continuously print on web page output of Python script?

Tags: php, python, ajax, python-3.x, shell-exec

I have a webpage which has some input tags which are passed to PHP to validate it and then php creates a command for another Python script to run and command is executed using `$output = shell_exec($cmd);` The Python script is a Selenium script which gives some output/status of what's going on while it's doing.

My question is that is there any way that I can use PHP to `shell_exec` the command created and display the output of Python script continuously? I can get all the output after the command is executed and not while the script is executing.

I searched on Google but didn't find any help. I read these answers, but they are not helping me...

[Python: how to show results on a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534070/python-how-to-show-results-on-a-web-page)

[Display python script output to HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641530/display-python-script-output-to-html-page)

[How to run python script in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460938/how-to-run-python-script-in-webpage)

[How to continuously display Python output in a Webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092961/how-to-continuously-display-python-output-in-a-webpage)

I don't want to use Flask or Django because my rest of the code is in PHP.

Comment: you can try enabling websockets in your python script and catch output of your script through websocket in your php script.

Comment: You can construct such things setting up a socket based client process forking instead of using `shell_exec()` which _per documentation_ first executes and the returns. Take a look at the `proc_open` function php offers: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php You will find various examples on the internet for this.

Comment: `shell_exec` etc. don't  use this method. Just create another *loopback* service for easily manage/cache control.

Comment: Thank you all for giving various suggestions. Can anyone please give some code?

Comment: I am still not able to use proc_open or popen in PHP. Can anyone please help me with the code and how to use the functions? I have not understood anything from the documentation...